# WS_FTP Pro / IpSwitch use to have 2 windows. How do I get it back

Tags: ftp

WS_FTP Pro a.k.a IpSwitch used to have two windows when I opened it.  One was for my local files and the other for the remote ftp site I was connected to.  I closed the local one however I'm unsure of how to get it back.  Does anyone know how to reopen this local window.  I typically would have local on the right and the ftp site on the left.  Now I have to drag and drop it from my computer onto IpSwitch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at WS_FTP V12 here. Open WS_FTP and look in the main menu. Pull down View (Beside Connection) and uncheck Single Pain view. That is a toggle between single and double pain.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks and good luck with WS_FTP going forward. I use this product myself on occasion